# Apply comma in awk on every element except the last one

Tags: awk, kubernetes

I want to get a list of all kubernetes nodes with seperated by comma for using it in `NO_PROXY` env variable and wrote the following commands:

```
kgnoowide | grep -v NAME | awk '{printf  "%s,", $1}'
```

This itself works, with a little detail missing: When having three nodes like

```
node1
node2
node3
```

my awk command returns `node1,node2,node3,`

So the last comma is wrong, a perfect output would be `node1,node2,node3`. I know this is a minor problem that could easily solved by simply removing the comma when pasting. But I'm interested how to solve this with `awk`, that itself is a very powerfull tool so I assume it should be possible. And it's also relevant for later usage in scripts, that e.g. generate a `~/.bashrc` entry with the correct `NO_PROXY` variable.

Comment: the `awk` answer already given suits as you need filter+join.. if you needed just join, `paste` would be handy.. for ex: `seq 3 | paste -sd,` will give `1,2,3`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need grep there

```
kgnoowide | awk '!/NAME/{out=(out sep $0);sep=","} END{print out}'
```